# My request returns null, but everything seems alright in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a router whose method is not called. In the main index.ts I have

```
app.use("/api/tshirts", tshirts)
```

Then in tshirts.ts I have

```
router.get("/", tshirtsController.getTShirts)

router.get("/:productId", 
tshirtsController.getTShirtByProductId)

router.get("/findProductsByIds", 
tshirtsController.getTShirtsByIds)

router.get("/other", (req, res) => {
  console.log("here")
  res.json({msg: "hello"})
})
```

When I try to hit this route with this URL: http://localhost:5050/api/tshirts/other in Postman, I don't get the console log in node and hello in the body of the response. I get null in the body and status 200. When I send requests to routes that don't exist I get status 404. The route is correct, everything seems ok but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: You need to provide more information, with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, it can be some wildcard positioned above in the code. Would need more details

Comment: I turned off all middleware this is basically the code. When I place the "/other" route on top of the routes it works, but the routes at the bottom don't work.

Comment: Routes using url parameters should be placed at the end of the code file, or routes placed below might not trigger. See my answer

Comment: Spring and Java don't do this, this is just a normal day in JS City.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route using `/:productId` will trigger for `/api/tshirts/other`

Try positioning the `/:productId` route after your `/other` route in tshirts.ts